# How do I convert Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>?

Tags: c#, .net

I can find lots of information about how to change the body of an expression, but I can't find anything about how to change the ReturnType.

Here is the code that I have written incorporating the call to the Convert routine given below.

```
    private T[] CheckCreatedOnDate<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldExpression, T[] input, Data.Context context) where T : Entity
    {
        var fieldDelegate = fieldExpression.Compile();

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateExpression = Convert(fieldExpression);  
        Func<T, bool> predicateDelegate = predicateExpression.Compile();
        Predicate<T> predicate = predicateDelegate.Invoke;

        DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        var data = dbSet.ToList();

        foreach (T inputRecord in input)
        {
            var fieldObject = fieldDelegate.Invoke(inputRecord);

            var dataRecord = data.SingleOrDefault(x => Equals(predicate, fieldObject));

            if (dataRecord != null)
            {
                inputRecord.CreatedOn = dataRecord.CreatedOn;
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

This method should behave in a very similar way to the AddOrUpdate method in EF, however this one simply replace the createdOn date if the record is already in the Db.

My code however still does not work. The predicate that is created does not seem to be correct as it never finds the relevant record in the Db.

All help much appreciated.

Cheers Mike

Comment: What did you try? What is your specific problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: well i dont think that return type of function you change at run time

Comment: Also, you might want to add a bit of code, like the Expression itself

Comment: I have added the code that I am working on. Sorry for not posting it earlier I was expecting the answer to be simple, but of course they never are :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `fieldExpression` is something like `(T e) => e.Field` I concluded that you want find in DB record with same value in `Field` column.

Try this:

```
foreach (T inputRecord in input)
{
    object fieldObject = fieldDelegate.Invoke(inputRecord);

    ParameterExpression p = fieldExpression.Parameters.First();
    // Equivalent to x => x.Field == fieldObject
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        // input.Field == fieldObject
        Expression.Equal(
            // input.Field
            fieldExpression.Body,
            // constant from fieldObject
            Expression.Constant(fieldObject)
        ),
        new []{ p }
    );

    T dataRecord = dbSet.SingleOrDefault(predicate);

    if (dataRecord != null)
    {
        inputRecord.CreatedOn = dataRecord.CreatedOn;
    }
}
```

I create totally new predicate in each loop run by taking `fieldExpression` body and pass it to `SingleOrDefault` invocation.

Comment: I have implemented your Convert method but still I cannot get my code to work. I have put the code in the questions now.

Comment: I've modified my answer

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks. Just one small thing, you also need to compile the predicate before passing it into SingleOrDefault. I have changed your code and marked it as the answer.

Comment: No you don't have to. When you compile it you'll use method for `IEnumerable` not from `IQueryable` which means that all data will be downloaded from server before filtering. When `IQueryable` is used it'll be translated into SQL

Comment: Sorry, you are right. In my code I already have all the data in memory so I need to compile it. But leaving it as you have it better because it does allow the data to come directly from the Db.